# Is it possible to capture the text on the recaptcha image and type the same in a text box using selenium rc

Tags: selenium

It is required for me to capture the text present on the recaptcha image and type the same in a text box. Can any one please share me the solution how can we do this using selenium rc or webdriver and share me the code also using java.

Answer (score 1):

You can not automate captcha, but there is some way to deal with captcha but for that human interaction is required.
 There are two ways in which you can automate CAPTCHA

1.By break command
2.By input-box

For input box

```
String captcha = selenium.getEval("prompt("Enter Captcha")");
selenium.type("fieldId", captcha);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I think, we have to enter the text present on the Captcha image in the prompt. Isn't it possible to store the text present on the captcha and type the text without manual interaction..? If possible, can you please share the code...

Comment: Purpose of the captcha is not to automate functionality, so this is not possible to store captcha image/text. There are only two ways to deal with captcha which i shared above.

Answer (score 1):

If it were possible, what would be the point of CAPTCHA images? If you bypass it in Selenium, what's stopping an attacker doing that? This is not possible, for very good reasons.

Instead just disable CAPTCHA for your test environment.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to "cheat" in your test environment I  would have the expected value added to a hidden field and pull from there.

Comment: What I would suggest is to put a setting in your config file to denote what environment you're in. DEV, TEST, PROD ect. 

On the page with your captcha if you're in DEV or TEST, populate a hidden field with the expected value of the captcha. I believe you should have access to the value in the code behind. 

Does that make sense at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is additional solution i described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935696/how-to-read-the-text-from-image-captcha/20660335#20660335) and it's to use CAPTCHA solver services API.

For example:
http://www.deathbycaptcha.com. You implementing their API, passing them the CAPTCHA and get in return the text.

Example for implementation [here](http://revan28.lima-city.de/death_by_captcha/readme.html).