# Google reCaptcha loading using BrowsermobProxy

Tags: java, selenium, http-proxy

I'm trying to load a webpage which contains Google reCaptcha using BrowserMobProxy. Although web page is loading but with captcha there are issues. Is that even possible?

Comment: Please can you post the code (or part of it)? Do you mean java or javascript? If you mean javascript, can you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: i mean java. I am trying to bypass captcha using Request Interceptor by modifying the request in proxy server..

Answer (score 1):

The main reason behind captcha is **NOT** to provide automation capabilities to the web application.

I think this has been answered many times in SO. [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859974/how-to-automate-captcha-using-selenium-webdriver), [Question2](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation)

If you need to automate a webpage with a captcha verification, the usual procedure is to request an application build that has captcha verifications disabled. 
The google captcha is tested by google anyway and you don't add any value to your test bed by verifying it's functionality.
You should be focusing on actual test scenarios in your app. And to verify if the captcha is working correctly with your app, you can have a single manual test case.

(This is if you are actually trying to test a web application. If you are up to something sketchy, well, you won't be able to do it. :) )

Comment: Is there any way I can block captcha from loading itself using Request interceptor?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. At least I don't know any way to do it. If you are testing an application request a captcha free build from the dev.