# re-captcha automation in selenium webdriver and ide

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to automate my singup form using selenium webdriver and ide. But, in my sign-up form, there is re-captcha just for security of the application. How do I handle re-captcha in both ide and webdriver.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Selenium WebDriver can't handle captcha functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no automation for re-captcha in selenium because selenium doesn't handle captcha. you need to test your sign-up form without re-captca by disabling them in the test environment.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can't handle captcha.

While website using captcha for the same reason so no one can automate their website using any robots.

You can ask your developers to provide you special environment where they bypass that captcha features or expose captcha value on DOM too so you can get the value of captcha on run time.

There is some 3rd party libraries are present who claim that they can automate captcha too but I never tried and heard that they are not efficient too.

Some references:

[How to read the text from image (captcha) by using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935696/how-to-read-the-text-from-image-captcha-by-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2012/11/automatingbreaking-captcha-using.html#.Vt5psdx94x8